# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm newbie in android development and when creating the application I've got error like this when I try to send new POST request.I would appreciate a quick reply, pointing out the error in my code and potential helping hand.

**ERROR**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ing, PID: 13835
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 29 path $.data
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:504)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 29 path $.data
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
...
```

**DATA CLASSES**

```
data class Employee (
    val status: String,
    val data: List<Data>
)
data class Data(
    val id: String,
    @SerializedName("employee_name")
    val employeeName: String,
    @SerializedName("employee_salary")
    val employeeSalary: String,
    @SerializedName("employee_age")
    val employeeAge: String,
    @SerializedName("profile_image")
    val profileImage: String
)
```

**INTERFACE**

```
@POST("create")
   suspend fun createEmployee(@Body employee: Employee):Employee
```

**ACTIVITY (without ui elements)**

```
class AddEmployeeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel: ViewModel


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_employee)

        DaggerComponent.create().inject(this)


        //Inputs
        val id:String 
        val name:String 
        val age:String 
        val salary:String 

        add.setOnClickListener {
            val data:List<Data> = addEmployee(id, name, age, salary)
            val newEmployee = Employee("success", data)
            try{
                viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(ViewModel::class.java)
                viewModel.createEmployee(newEmployee)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)

            }catch (e:Exception){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failure!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            }
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Please search for the error message, before asking questions that had been asked countless times already. If I wouldn't too tired, I'd close it... see the bottom right side, below "Related".

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem

```
val data: List<Data>
```

Have the same problem and the only solution I found was

`val data: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

Can't find anywhere how to use the second data class inside the first always error.
Then I get the position 0 of the first array and inside is the other array with the data to the second class (Data) in your example.
I hope somebody show us the real solution to this problem many people is having and don't understand where is the error.
Good luck.